# Command (Store) is not available for driver (Gd) intervention image in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

i use intervention image laravel...
laravel 5.7 amd PHP 7.2

when i am resize image and save to DB,, error like this

```
Command (Store) is not available for driver (Gd).
```

this is my controller

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'tittle' => 'required|string|unique:banners|max:255'
    ],[
        'tittle.required' => 'Tittle sudah ada',
     ]);
    $data = $request->all();
    $file= Image::make($request->file('file'))->store('uploads/file','public');
    $path= $file->resize(150,150);
    $this->repo->create([$data,$path]);
    return redirect()->route('banner.index')->with('alert', ['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Data inserted successfully']);
}
```

i have been follow the instruction o documentation

```
 php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"
```

,,

but error like above... help 
thanks

Comment: did you try `save` instead of store

Comment: store() method expect a file object not an image.

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
$path = $request->file('file')->store('uploads/file', 'public');
Image::make(storage_path($path))->resize(150,150)->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 $file= Image::make($request->file('file'))->store('uploads/file','public');
```

try

```
  $file= Image::make($request->file('file'))->encode("jpg", 75);
  Storage::disk('public')->put( 'uploads/file' . 'myfile.jpg',(string) $file);
```