# Call to a member function getRealPath() on null (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Can anyone help me how to implement resizing image in Laravel?
I have this code only:

Controller

```
/* Save Image in Floder public>storage>images>service_request */
                $nameFile = $service_request_id."_".date("Ymdhis")."_";
                $count = 1;
                for($i=1 ; $i<=3 ; $i++){
                    if($request->hasFile('problem_image'.$i)){
                        //$md5Name = md5_file($request->file('service_request')->getRealPath());
                        $md5Name = $nameFile.str_pad($count, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                        $guessExtension = $request->file('problem_image'.$i)->guessExtension();
                        $image        = $request->file('problem_image'.$i);
                        $filename     = $md5Name.'.'.$guessExtension;
                        $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());              
                        $image_resize->resize(300, 300);
                        $file = $image_resize->storeAs('images/service_request', $filename, 'public' );
                        $ImageServiceRequest = new ImageServiceRequest;
                        $ImageServiceRequest->service_request_id = $service_request_id;
                        $ImageServiceRequest->image = $file;
                        $ImageServiceRequest->status = 'Active';
                        $ImageServiceRequest->create_by = Auth::user()->id;;
                        $ImageServiceRequest->save();
                        
                        $count++;
                    }
```

Comment: You're checking if the request has `'problem_image'.$i` but then only use `$request->file('problem_image');` as image, which doesn't exist/is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using numbered `problem_image`.

Change this line of code.

From :

```
$image = $request->file('problem_image');
```

To:

```
$image = $request->file('problem_image'.$i);
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Now I got it but it error this instead " Command (StoreAs) is not available for driver (Gd)."

Comment: check this answer . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122135/command-store-is-not-available-for-driver-gd-intervention-image-in-laravel-5